Bruno: Is there a way to export sent request in curl?
I need to copy as curl a request sent by bruno.  I tried to do it inside the timeline tab or by inspecting the developer tool. But none of them allows this possibility.
Is there a way to achieve it?

What does "none of them work for me" mean? What happens when you do it? Do you get an error message? Unexpected response from theserver? Does your computer explode?

Thanks for your comment, it simply means the feature is not available. I will update the question.

There is no such feature as far as I see it. You may be interested in filing an issue at the official repository.

In the left sidebar, mouse over your request. Click the 3 dots that appear '...'. Choose 'Generate Code'. In the window that appears, select 'Shell-Curl'.

This works if there is no auth. Unfortunately it currently doesn't include authentication headers, for example for Basic or Bearer Authentication.

It's not what I was expected because I want to export exactly what I send, not what is saved in the bruno env.

Jens Geiregat's answer was not all when I wanted to test my API. curl by default adds a header Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded which was not understood by my API. In addition to the curl command generated by Bruno, I needed the option -H 'Content-Type:'. That option suppressed the unwanted header.
EDIT: This worked under MinGW, not in a DOS prompt.
